# iOS: editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath when adding a new cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm adding a row to a UITableView section when the user switches the table to editing mode with this code:

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL) editing animated:(BOOL) animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing) {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:SECTION_SUPPLIERS]]   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } 
}
```

The object being to create a "Add new supplier ..." row. This works, however when the table wants to get the editing style so it can add a plus or minus icon, I have a problem.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    return ([self.tableView isEditing] && indexPath.row == 0) ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert : UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

The sequence seems to go like this:

1. The table switches to editing. There is only one supplier row at this time so it queries for a editing style with row == 0.
2. The insert of the new row is done which then triggers another query for an editing style again with a row == 0.

So if I use this sequence and use the row number and tableView isEditing to decide on the editing style icon I end up with both the Add new and current supplier rows with plus icons on them.

What is the best way to insert a row and assign the appropriate editing style - plus for the add new row, and minus for any other row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting your "Add new..." row at the bottom instead of at the top? Instead of checking for `[indexPath row] == 0` you instead check for `[indexPath row] == [items count]`, and your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` implementation looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int numberOfRows = [items count];

    if ([self isEditing]) {
        numberOfRows++;
    }

    return numberOfRows;
}
```

This is how the example in iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide works.

Comment: Thanks, I already have something like that code in place. What I'm trying to figure out is how to tell which cell is being queried when the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath message is sent. The Part of the problem seems to be that whilst the insert has been executed, the UITableView hasn't actually added the cell because the code has not returned to the run loop yet.

Comment: To give further details - if I add code to the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath method which queries the UITableView for the row of the indexPath. After inserting the new cell, I will still get back the current cell because the UITableView does not yet have the new Add cell in place. I have to wait for the run loop to execute and animations to happen before that occurs.